# Is there an expression for $\mu(n)^2$ where $\mu$ is the mobius function?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Is there an expression for $\mu(n)^2$ where $\mu$ is the mobius function?

I know that 
\begin{align}
\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)=\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & \text{if }n=1\\
0 & \text{if }n>1
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

and that

\begin{align}
\mu(n)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
0 & \text{if } n \text{ has one or more repeated prime factors}\\
1 & \text{if }n=1\\
(-1)^k & \text{if } n \text{ is a product of } k \text{ distinct primes}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

I am trying to find an expression for $\mu(n)^2$ because I am trying to show that $$\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)^2 = 2^k$$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ ie. show that it is a power of 2.

Any hints or suggestions would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Hint: factorize $n= p_1^{a_1} \cdots p_r^{a_r}$, and call $m = p_1 \cdots p_r$. Then it can be easily shown  that $\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)^2 = \sum_{d|m} \mu(d)^2$. So without loss of generality you can consider $n$ squarefree.

Comment: $\mu(n)^2$ is an expression for $\mu(n)^2$, and you won't find a simpler one. What do you really mean to ask? Also, in your last display, what's that $k$ on the right side? Izzat sposed to be an $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Since $\mu(d)^2=0$ if $d$ has repeated prime factors, and $\mu(d)^2=1$ otherwise, you need to count how many $d$ dividing $n$ have no repeated prime factors.

*Solution:*

> These $d$ are exactly the product of subsets of the prime factors of $n$, of which there are $2^k$ in total, where $k$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$.